# DataDog events are auto-recovered

Tags: datadog

I created an event monitor that catches events with errors and notifies about the alert in a special messenger. Everything worked out for me, but I noticed that such alerts are auto-recovered on their own for some time.

As I understand it is because of this parameter:
[image]

So, datadog catches event, then sets event-monitor in alert status, then wait 5min-48hours and if there are no new events, it is auto-recovered and set status from "Alert" to "OK". It absolutely does not suit me. Can I somehow configure the monitor that the monitor's status does not change automatically from "Alert" to "OK" until I change it manually?

Comment: did you manged to fix it?

Answer (score 13):

Attached Screenshot:

[image]

Add your slack handle under the is_alert function only. This way it will not automatically send you auto recovered massages